# Switch a line level audio signal - which chip is best WRT noise, low loss?

Tags: arduino, audio, opto-isolator, acoustic-noise

I am relatively unexperienced with audio circuits, and need to switch a standard line level signal, AC, about 6Vpp. I have the chips listed below, and would very much appreciate some pointers as to which would be best - I only need to switch stereo between 2-4 paths, and could use relays if they didn’t consume so much power compared to these.  It’s important to keep noise away from the audio, so I am considering switching the chips with optocouplers from arduino pins, likely the PC817. Would this be best practice, or just a waste of space on my board?

- CD4053BE
- CD4012BE
- CD4013BE
- CD4066BE
- MC14015BCP
- HCF4072BE
- HCF4002BE
- TC4015BP

And on the very *off* chance I can use this, I’ll also list

- 74HC4051N

If there’s something that’s not clear, let me know. I have all the relevant datasheets, but most of these claim to be low-noise or noise-free. Which is the best for this? Thanks!

Comment: The optocouplers are probably a waste of space. You just add proper filtering in any line that runs between Pi and switch. So, all these ICs have proper data sheets that list their properties – are you asking us how to get that data from the data sheet? (that'd be a very valid question!!)

Comment: HCF4072BE, HCF4002BE, CD4012BE, CD4013BE and MC14015BCP are pure digital logic gates, flip-flops and stuff like that. How can you eventually consider using them as analog switches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What component to use for audio signal switching?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95598/what-component-to-use-for-audio-signal-switching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HC4051 is ideal if you use +-5V and clip or attenuate line signal to same otherwise latchup fault will occur.

Search for modern HV (supply) variations of this .

CD4053B supports +/-10Vdc. Perhaps like most CD series.

Although higher resistance CD4051 can run off +/-8V or 16Vdc,  or similar but Ac coupled from in and output biased to Vdd/2 on in/out.

Line impedance standard is 10k load

But noise EMC is all about wiring , layout, shielding and conducted/radiated PS noise and Common Mode impedance noise reduction, ground paths and has nothing to do with chip.

Comment: He specifically did that.

Comment: No? read his second sentence.