# Performance of a back-to-back NMOS for analog switching

Tags: analog, analog-switch

I wanted to make an analog switch in a pinch, so I cobbled together a quick back-to-back N-Channel MOSFET analog switch using junk box parts. It actually seems to work quite well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk8D2N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Plot of audio switching]

I also tried this with PMOS and achieved similar results.

From my plot, I noticed the rise delay on switching off. Curiously, this was made more noticable by the introduction of C3 and C4 (needed to make the signal quiet when the FET is off). I wonder if this is a characteristic of low performance in my circuit.

From another answer (on [audio switching](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95598/what-component-to-use-for-audio-signal-switching)), I see that the [DG408](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70062/dg408.pdf) analog multiplexer or [MAX4066](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max4066-max4066a.pdf) analog switch can be used for analog switching, but in a pinch, does my back-to-back NMOS configuration work just as well? Would it be appropriate for a production design? I appreciate that an IC would reduce the part count, so my question is academic. From reading the datasheets of the switch and multiplexer I mentioned, the internal workings for both are illustrated using a toggle switch, but I imagine they'd need to use some kind of FET.

Side note: I suppose using a JFET might eliminate the back-to-back MOSFET need, as it doesn't have the body diode, but I don't have any handy. That said, I read that while the JFET doesn't have a body diode, it is [useless for everything but some niche signal stuff](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/125121/288848).

Edit: As suggested in the answers, I tried reducing Rload to 100 Ω, and this does indeed affect the lingering output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSLWa.png)</sup>

[image: Plot with 100 Ω Rload]

Further changes indicate that actually, a 100 nF cap (C5) to ground performs well enough compared to C3 and C4 previously. I can't seem to simulate this noise problem in CircuitLab/SPICE, but in the physical circuit, here's the waveform...

**Without C5:**
[image: Scope view - without C5]

40 mV is just about audible through speakers, and is unmistakably the same sound at 1/10 of the volume.

**With C5:**
[image: Scope view - with C5]

10 mV is the same as the background noise.

Comment: It might help if you showed the output waveform when C3 and C4 are removed. Both aren't needed anyway. And, probably C1 isn't needed either. How fast do you want it to switch from on to off and from off to on? A solid state relay normally has both sources commoned i.e. your MOSFETs would be both swapped D->S. Additionally, the DS capacitance will be quite significant with an input in the low voltage region and this causes a worse level of feed-through when supposedly "off".

Comment: Pretty slow switching, it's for user-initiated a mute function, so probably will always be less than 10 Hz.

Comment: @Andyaka Updated question to show photos of the waveform with and without C5 (which replaced C3 and C4). Yes, C1 isn't needed for the physical circuit, but without it, a 3 megavolt spike appears on the SPICE plot. A weird simulator quirk.

Comment: Obviously, your SW voltage needs to be substantially greater than the switched signal voltage; I assume that's not a problem here, but it needs to be considered.

Comment: I did consider adding a FET for this, but the sim worked without, so I decided to keep it simple.

Comment: I screwed around a bunch with these types of switches. The biggest problem (already mentioned) is the capacitance between IN and OUT when the device is supposed to be OFF. Do an AC analysis in SPICE to see how bad it gets as the frequency of your signal goes up. A note about the analog switch ICs:  You actually can't duplicate how they work with discrete MOSFETs. The are built with parallel NMOS and PMOS FETs but take advantage that the body terminals are connected to VSS and VDD respectively. This is what allows them to work. You don't have access to the body terminals in discrete MOSFETs.

Answer (score 4):

A few words on the JFET (ex. N-JFET). It works indeed as a bipolar switch. If you pull the gate low, it turns off. The advantage is that it has rather modest off-capacitance, which is good.

However, its on-properties are a little bit more difficult:

- channel resistance is usually between 10..100 Ω depending on the part, which is on the high side. So it's fine for audio signals, but not for speaker drive.
- you can't pull the gate high as with a MOSFET, or you will pull the channel high, too. Instead you have to pull the gate to the channel.
- Therefore you need at least another switch, and cannot implement it using just a bistable logic output to drive the gate. That removes one of the main advantages. In the simplest case you can use a diode. When you pull the gate low, the diode conducts, when the control signal goes high, the resistor pulls the gate to the channel.
- The second resistor to the most positive supply makes sure that the gate  is more negative than the channel at both ends, to allow reliable turn-off

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuVxyX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that this switch will turn-on when the signal voltage becomes so negative that it is close to the negative rail. So while it can block most of the voltage range, it is not fully rail-to-rail. In this regard, it has a similarity with the 4-terminal NMOS analog switch, which cannot *pass* rail-to-rail voltages when on.

The upshot is that JFET are available with very small turn-off voltages such as 0.5 V and less. That means that you lose only a small voltage range and that allows this solution to be somewhat useful for 3.3V and 5V systems. If you have an analog voltage range that is much larger than the digital voltage range of the control signal, you can use another small-signal transistor instead of the diode, to pull the gate down in an open-drain/collector fashion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhJ6UH.png)</sup>

Comment: Nice, I was wondering about this.

Comment: I can only get your circuit to turn off if the ON/OFF signal is pulled below the threshold voltage of the JFET.  In this case, Vto=-3.4 for the J310 SPICE model, so it starts to turn on at any voltage above that.  Am I missing something or is this exactly what you meant by "pull the gate low"?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkBtb.png

Comment: @SteKulov 1) the 310 is the default in the schematic editor. better use a modern part with e.g. Vto~-0.5 V. 2) consider a 0-5V supply, and signals at typically half supply voltage, i.e. ~2.5 V. Then it should make more sense.

Comment: @tobalt  I still don't understand.  If Vto= -0.5V, then you still need something more negative than that to turn it off.  If you only have 0-5V supply, you'll need to generate a negative supply...otherwise the FET will remain open on any control voltage between 0-5V.  That's what my dc sweep simulation is showing, unless I did something wrong.  I can only get what you describe if I use a P-channel JFET with a low Vto and flip the diode around. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO9vw.png

Comment: @SteKulov Hmm I think you are right. I didn't simulate it, maybe I remember it wrongly. What if R2 goes to 5V instead? (that is equivalent then to your PFET variant)

Comment: @SteKulov I have simulated it now. And ammended my answer. The second resistor should indeed go to the positive (and not negative) supply.

Comment: @tobalt  Ahhh...excellent!  Makes sense.  Thanks for looking into it and making the corrections.  OFF isolation for AC is pretty phenomenal with these.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> From my plot, I noticed the rise delay on switching off.

This is caused by the capacitive load suddenly being disconnected from the source, and having to rely, thereafter, on Rload to charge/discharge those caps.

Your source V1 has 0Ω impedance, and is able to provide all the current necessary (MOSFET drain-source resistance notwithstanding) to instantly charge the load capacitance to its own voltage at any instant in time.

In reality that would not happen, since the source will have some impedance, but in your simulation, the only reason you see the output following the input with such fidelity is this extremely strong source.

If the source happens to be at exactly zero volts at the instant when the MOSFETs switch off, then the capacitors at the output will be in a charge state where the output is also zero. However, if at that instant the source and output are non-zero, then the only path remaining for current to eventually bring the output to ground, is Rload, and you see a classic RC discharge curve at the output.

If you reduce Rload to, say, 100Ω I suspect you would see that "lingering" output voltage all but disappear.

I think it's likely your DIY switch will work just as well as an integrated circuit, for many applications, but may suffer under certain conditions merely due to the size of the circuit and routing of signals. For example, with an IC, you can probably expect shorter delays between the digital control input transition and the switch actually opening and closing, merely due to the physically smaller size, but I doubt this is of much consequence in typical, low frequency applications.

That said, if you are careless with your own layout and signal routing, you could easily produce a switch with appalling characteristics, which is not an indictment of the DIY approach, just a result of carelessness.

Comment: I added a quote for context, is this the one you're referring to?

Comment: @NickBolton Yes. By the way, switch everything in the room off, like lights, TV, anything that you don't need for troubleshooting this circuit. Eliminate those possible noise sources before you waste hours trying to find noise in your own circuit.

Comment: Yep, discovered this. Lots of clicks and pops caused by AC devices turning on and off.